# drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies Errors

Tags: server, 20.04, kernel

I am having below errors in dmesg on ubuntu 20.04 on kernel 5.4.0-81-generic. I am using ubuntu VM on vsphere 7.0.

[Fri Sep  3 20:39:13 2021] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:38:crtc-0] flip_done timed out
[Fri Sep  3 20:39:24 2021] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:34:plane-0] flip_done timed out
[Sun Sep  5 14:13:38 2021] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:38:crtc-0] flip_done timed out
[Sun Sep  5 14:13:49 2021] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [PLANE:34:plane-0] flip_done timed out

The console of VM got stuck and flooded with above errors make me unable to write things.